# 502 Bad gateway WCF does not respond

Tags: wcf, ssl, https

IIS6

-- I have a server on my network which have a network name called Test_Server.  It is connected to ISA proxy.

-- I have a server a domain name called Live_Server having the IP Live_IP.  It is not connected to any proxy. or suppose to be.

-- off course I open all firewall ports

--I have a WCF REST service, I use HTTPS to connect to it, everything is fine on:-

- 127.0.0.1:SomePort
- test_Server:SomePort

--When I connect WCF Rest to any of the following using HTTPS request:-

**I get 502 Bad gateway error and the exception status is System.Net.WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError**

- Live_Server:SomePort
- Live_IP:SomePort

What is chances??

The following is the web.config of WCF

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="Contracts.WCF_REST">
      <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="webHttp" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SecureWebHttp" contract="Contracts.IWCF_REST" />
    </service>
  </services>

  <bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding name="SecureWebHttp" useDefaultWebProxy="false">
        <security mode="Transport">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"/>
        </security>
      </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="webHttp">
        <webHttp/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

End of madness

As far as I understand, The client was detecting a proxy and was trying to connect through it. I simply asked .net to stop using any proxy found at the client.

but I am still don't get it, why it woks fine with HTTP and failed to work with HTTPS.  HTTPS works only when I stop using the proxy.

**Someone have better explanation?**

```
  WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have seen such problem when connecting an on-premise WCF services to Azure-hosted Web Role and these are mostly caused by having proxy in on-premise network. In any enterprise IT environment all machines network setting is set to use Proxy server either Auto detect or if you have multiple proxy server you actually set which one to choose. When WCF service connect outside world it goes through same proxy settings and that actually changes the dynamics of connecting it and introduce the behavior.

So why with HTTPS, not with HTTP, this is because HTTPS uses TLS to secure the communication and if you have proxy in middle it is very much possible that WCF communication could not be established.

By setting UseDefaultWebProxy to false you are asking web service to not use machine specific proxy and use user setting which is part of your web service configuration. And this way you can impose your WCF specific configuration establish HTTPS connection over machine specific Proxy.